# how do I time a command so not greater then 30secs

Tags: powershell

I wrote the below code that works fine - it sets each network card to enabled (and waits until a card has a `$StatusConnected=2`).

The problem I see when I roll this out to production on all servers is that there will be some dodgy servers whereby it just will not be able to change the status to 2 and will loop forever in trying to get it to 2.

Any one know how I can put a timer on the below so that if it does not change 2 in 30seconds then move onto the next card? Would be handy if it could also show me the card that it failed on.

Do I add another `Do` and put a timer like `-gt 30` ? - not too sure how to start on this so any ideas would be useful - plus, hard to test as all my lab servers work fine in enabling NICs.

```
$listofNIcs = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -ComputerName . -filter "Name LIKE '%HP%' OR Name LIKE '%Broadcom%' OR NAME LIKE '%Intel%'"
$StatusConnected = $listofNIcs.NetConnectionStatus

Foreach ($disNICS in $listofNIcs) 
    { 
        Do {
            $disNICS.Enable()
            }
        Until($StatusConnected -eq "2")           

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd just grab the time and compare it in your loop condition.

```
Foreach ($disNICS in $listofNIcs) 
    {
        $StartTime = Get-Date; 
        Do {
            $disNICS.Enable()
            }
        Until(($StatusConnected -eq "2") -or (((Get-Date) - $StartTime).TotalSeconds -gt 30))

    }
```

Note: I originally had Seconds here instead of TotalSeconds.  You really want TotalSeconds.  Seconds is just the second component, so if it's 5 hours 4 minutes and 13 seconds, Seconds would be 13, while TotalSeconds would be 18253.